# Bootstrap Border on top (right above) a bottom border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I put a border on top of a border? Part of my Header is a banner and the other is text with a bottom border blending with the banner. There is one color shade different i would like to make a 1px solid line on top of the border I have created. Is it possible to put a border on top of a border?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default mega-menu" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <a href="#"><img id="logo-header" class="header-banner img-responsive" src="assets/img/ptaximg/topgraphicptax.jpg" width="1000" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                           <div id="border" class="col-md-2">
                                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                    <img src="assets/img/ptaximg/ptax-logo_sm.jpg" alt="Logo">-->
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.pacificbluesoftware.com/">
                                    <img src="assets/img/ptaximg/ptax-logo_sm.jpg">
                                    <p class="powered_by text-center">Powered by</p>
                                    <p class="powered_by text-center"><strong>Pacific Blue Software, Inc.</strong></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <span class="full-width-menu">Menu Bar</span>
                            <span class="icon-toggle">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

#border{
    border-bottom: solid 27px #296488;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Im trying to put a 1px border right above this border i created border-bottom: solid 27px #296488;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow` to create a double border like this:

```
#border{
    border-bottom: solid 27px #296488;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 1px -10px red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the :after and :before classes:

```css
   #border{
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: solid 20px #296488;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
   #border:before{
    content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -22px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffea00;
    
   }
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default mega-menu" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <a href="#"><img id="logo-header" class="header-banner img-responsive" src="assets/img/ptaximg/topgraphicptax.jpg" width="1000" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                           <div id="border" class="col-md-2">
                                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                    <img src="assets/img/ptaximg/ptax-logo_sm.jpg" alt="Logo">-->
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.pacificbluesoftware.com/">
                                    <img src="assets/img/ptaximg/ptax-logo_sm.jpg">
                                    <p class="powered_by text-center">Powered by</p>
                                    <p class="powered_by text-center"><strong>Pacific Blue Software, Inc.</strong></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <span class="full-width-menu">Menu Bar</span>
                            <span class="icon-toggle">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Obviously it's Bootstrap so it doesn't look amazing.